# Matching 2 columns in R, omitting cases where one variable entry is "."

Tags: r

I'm new to R (2 weeks) and am trying to figure out the following:

The row numbers where one column does not match the other. i.e. `AA == BB`. I know how to use the ifelse function and have used this code:

```
df$check <- ifelse(df$var1== 1 & df$var2== 1,1,0)
df[df$check==0,]
```

This identifies the rows where this is not the case. Only problem is I have instances where the entry in `df$var2` is "." I only want to get row numbers where `df$var1 == 1` and `df$var2 == 0` (or vice versa). Using the above code includes where `df$var1 == 1` and `df$var2 == "."`

Comment: You should include a little of your data (eg paste in head(df)), and your desired output.

Comment: Is the target to learn `ifelse` ? Because according to your use of `ifelse`, you can omit it completely as `<logical vector> & <logical vector>` will return a logical vector totally suited to subset a data frame.

Comment: Short made long according to your description `df[df$var %in% c(0,1) & df$var2 %in% c(0,1),]` Explanation: `df$var1 %in% c(0,1)` will return a logical vector of rows where `df$var1` is 0 or 1, same for var2, combining both with & and you get all row where var1 and var
2 are 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

You could nest another ifelse in the else part of your ifelse statement.

Ifelse(as you have it, 1, ifelse(df$var2==".",2,0))

Then continue as you had it.

The "which" function is probably your best bet.

select = which(df$var1!=df$var2&df$var2!=".")
df[select,]

!= means not equal

Comment: Please format your code... (use the button once the text is selected or press ctrl + K)

Answer (score 0):

Long version of the comment (of course you can inverse the match of `%in%` with `!` like this:

`!(vector %in% another_vector)`

Example code with positive matching:

```
set.seed(123) # Fix the generator
#Build the data frame
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(0,1),30,replace=T), var2=sample(c(0,1,"."),30,replace=T))

lv1 <- df$var1 %in% c(0,1) # First logical vector
lv2 <- df$var2 %in% c(0,1) # Same as lv1

slv <- lv1 & lv2 # combine them

df[slv,] #Do the select
```

The generated df looks like (first 6 row on 30):

```
> head(df)
  var1 var2
1    0    .
2    1    .
3    0    .
4    1    .
5    1    0
6    0    1
```

lv2 looks like (I let you see the other **L**ogical **V**ectors variable by yourself:

```
> lv2
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[18]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And the final output:

```
> df[slv,] #Do the select
   var1 var2
5     1    0
6     0    1
8     1    0
9     1    0
10    0    0
11    1    0
12    0    1
13    1    1
14    1    1
15    0    0
16    1    0
17    0    0
18    0    1
19    0    0
21    1    0
22    1    1
24    1    0
25    1    1
26    1    0
27    1    0
30    0    1
```